# How to debug Mobicents Media Server

Tags: debugging, server, webrtc, mobicents, restcomm

I'm using RestComm Client iOS SDK to make a call to my  RestComm instance deployed locally, but I'm having issues setting up a WebRTC call (something seems to be wrong with the STUN pings as part of ICE). How can I attach the eclipse debugger on the RestComm Media Server?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find instructions on how to do that at https://github.com/Mobicents/mediaserver/wiki/SettingUpDevEnvForMMSContributors#enabling-mms-remote-debugging